# Can't unwrap Optional.None with AutoreleasingUnsafePointer

Tags: swift

Upon running `NSAppleScript.executeAndReturnError` with an Applescript command that should fail and return an error, I get a `Can't unwrap Optional.None` error for `errorDict`.

```
var errorDict: NSDictionary? = nil
var scriptObject:NSAppleScript = NSAppleScript(source: command)
var execute:NSAppleEventDescriptor = scriptObject.executeAndReturnError(&errorDict)
```

I understand that the error is due to unwrapping a `nil` optional variable, though `executeAndReturnError` must take an optional variable. How could I fix this?

Answer (score 5):

This error is most likely occurring while trying to initialize the `NSAppleScript` object, not your `NSDictionary?` object. `NSAppleScript(source:)` is a [failable initializer](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=17), meaning it could return `nil` if an error occurs compiling your script. Your code should look something like this:

```
if let scriptObject = NSAppleScript(source: command) {
    var errorDict: NSDictionary? = nil
    let execute = scriptObject.executeAndReturnError(&errorDict)
    if errorDict != nil {
        // script execution failed, handle error
    }
} else {
   // script failed to compile, handle error
}
```

Sulthan's answer makes a good point, but as of Swift 1.2, `executeAndReturnError(errorInfo:)` no longer returns an `Optional` type even though it could return a `nil` (see this [radar](https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5614137677709312)). The proper way to handle the execution failing is by checking the `errorInfo` dictionary for errors.